# Migrate foreign key type from char to binary - ways to deal with the fallout?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, migration, ddl

I am in the process of slimming down a database that has been using `char`/`varchar` fields where `binary`/`varbinary` would be a better choice (given the data represented is byte arrays).

One of the fields I am changing is used in foreign key contraints on a number of other tables.

I cannot drop the current FK constraints, migrate the column to its new type and then simply re-create the FK constraints as the data types would not match.

What approach should I take in migrating this? How would you go about it?

Answer (score 5):

Given the next example:

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    [ID] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
);

CREATE TABLE B 
(
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    [A_ID] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_B] FOREIGN KEY ([A_ID]) REFERENCES A([ID])
);

CREATE TABLE C 
(
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    [A_ID] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_C] FOREIGN KEY ([A_ID]) REFERENCES A([ID])
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES ('001'), ('010'), ('100');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, '001'), (2, '001'), (3, '010');
INSERT INTO C VALUES (4, '010'), (5, '100'), (6, '100');
```

0- Backup, backup & backup your database.

1- Due you are trying to convert varchar to varbinary and there isn't an explicit conversion you should add new columns to your tables. **NOTE: You cannot make it non nullables**.

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD [ID_VB] VARBINARY(10);
ALTER TABLE B ADD [A_ID_VB] VARBINARY(10);
ALTER TABLE C ADD [A_ID_VB] VARBINARY(10);
```

2- Copy current values to the new columns:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  UPDATE A SET [ID_VB] = CAST([ID] AS VARBINARY(10));
  UPDATE B SET [A_ID_VB] = CAST([A_ID] AS VARBINARY(10));
  UPDATE C SET [A_ID_VB] = CAST([A_ID] AS VARBINARY(10));
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

3- Drop current constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_B];
ALTER TABLE C DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_C];
ALTER TABLE A DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_A];
```

4- Once you have checked new values are correct, drop actual columns:

```
ALTER TABLE A DROP COLUMN [ID];
ALTER TABLE B DROP COLUMN [A_ID];
ALTER TABLE C DROP COLUMN [A_ID];
```

5- Rename new columns with old names:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'A.ID_VB', 'ID', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename 'B.A_ID_VB', 'A_ID', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename 'C.A_ID_VB', 'A_ID', 'COLUMN';
```

6- Make new columns not nullables:

```
ALTER TABLE A ALTER COLUMN [ID] VARBINARY(10) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE B ALTER COLUMN [A_ID] VARBINARY(10) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE C ALTER COLUMN [A_ID] VARBINARY(10) NOT NULL;
```

7- Add constraints again:

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_B] FOREIGN KEY ([A_ID]) REFERENCES A([ID]);
ALTER TABLE C ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_C] FOREIGN KEY ([A_ID]) REFERENCES A([ID]);
```

8- Check final result:

```
SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM B;
SELECT * FROM C;
```

> ```
> | ID       |
> | :------- |
> | 0x303031 |
> | 0x303130 |
> | 0x313030 |
>
> ID | A_ID    
> -: | :-------
>  1 | 0x303031
>  2 | 0x303031
>  3 | 0x303130
>
> ID | A_ID    
> -: | :-------
>  4 | 0x303130
>  5 | 0x313030
>  6 | 0x313030
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7f88b5e47270e3bf309101fb2657933c)*

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but if you are going to go to these lengths, I would think changing the the RI to use a surrogate key instead of the raw data would be a better approach in general, though that may require some additional code changes on the app side.

Comment: You **can** make it none nullable by adding a default (e.g. `0x`). Adding a column with a (runtime constant) default is a metadata only change in Enterprise Edition.  Dropping the default when needed later is a metadata only change unlike changing the column property to `not null` - which is a size of data operation

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the relationate both data need has same data type.

> One of the fields I am changing is used in foreign key contraints on a
>   number of other tables.

So I can't see another solution to do this:

Create a new column in table A and change constraint in table B to this new column:

```
1 - Create another column (colX) in table A
2 - Cast and repply date into column colX 
3 - Remove constraint FK of table B
4 - Cast data type in table B
5 - Create a new constraint FK in table B with colX of table A
```

You can create a trigger to populate this new column in table A, but keep caution if you use trigger. Is necessary documentation and caution in future actions.